# Web and Mobile backend framework and protocol

Tags: android, mobile, web, frameworks, backend

I am looking forward to build a mobile application, android for now but will be extendable to iOS and also a Web app. I am planning to build a common backend and use REST and expose the API's which will be consumed from different applications. 
I am looking for suggestions for a technology stack best suitable for this kind of architecture?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/). The main advantage being that it is super easy to set up and it does all the things you would normally expect from a REST service. JSON serialization, routes, parameters etc...

And you can code it in C# .NET, without having to write the boilerplate code that is usually necessary to get this sort of simple functionality running.

Comment: But does it support Python? I am planning to build the backend in Python and expose the api's for mobile apps as well.